# Getting Angular variables from different modules and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to understand it is possible to communicate between Controllers under different modules. Is this even possible?

Here is my test that I am trying to learn from:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">  
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <p data-ng-bind="group.name"></p>
        <p data-ng-bind="project.name"></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ProjectCtrl">
        <p data-ng-bind="group.name"></p>
        <p data-ng-bind="project.name"></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="GroupCtrl">
        <p data-ng-bind="group.name"></p>
        <p data-ng-bind="project.name"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['project', 'group']);
var group = angular.module('group', ['project']);
var project = angular.module('project', ['group']);


app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'Project', 'Group', function($scope, $project, $group) {
    $scope.project = Project;
    $scope.group = Group;
    $scope.name = 'My App';
}]);

project.controller('ProjectCtrl', ['$scope', 'Project', 'Group', function($scope, $project, $group) {
   $scope.project = Project;
    $scope.group = Group;
    $scope.name = 'My Project';
}]);

group.controller('GroupCtrl', ['$scope', 'Project', 'Group', function($scope, $project, $group) {
    $scope.project = Project;
    $scope.group = Group;
    $scope.name = 'My Group';
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6kqszmuz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, using Broadcast or Emit. All controllers have access to a $rootScope. What you can do is broadcast a message to the rootscope, and then define $on methods on your other controllers. These in turn listen to events firing in the rootscope. 
Have a look at $broadcast in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope and $on.

I think you are trying to re-use viewmodels and that's something I wouldn't do.